# ASP.Net Web API 2 Different Content when authorized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I have a project that's using ASP.Net Web API 2, and providing oAuth support via the OWIN oAuth 2 provider. Everything is working fine, but I have hit upon a problem when trying to differentiate between authenticated users and anonymous users.

I can easily provide the [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] attributes, but neither quite does what I want to do. [Authorize] will only allow authorised users, and [AllowAnonymous] will allow anyone, authenticated or not.

The behaviour that I'm looking for is as follows:

- User requests the endpoint with **no authorization header** in their request - the anonymous version of the endpoint's content is returned
- User requests the endpoint with a **valid authorization header** in their request - the logged in version of the endpoint's content is returned
- User requests the endpoint with an **invalid authorisation header** in their request - the server returns a status code of 401

I can build a custom attribute that will do this, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this natively without having to create a custom attribute.

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Richard.

**UPDATE**

One option I've come up with is to create a subclass of the AuthorizeAttribute like this:

```
public class SuccessfulAuthorizationOrAnonymousAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        else
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
            {
                // If there's an authorization header, but there Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false, then authentication must have failed
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // There's no authorization header - therefore the user cannot have attempted to authenticate. A true anonymous request?
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The logic is that if the user comes through to this attribute as authenticated, then I can let the base class handle whether they're actually authorised to view the content.

However, if they come through as unauthenticated, then I can check to see if there was an Authorisation  header in the request, and if there was then I think I can infer that the authentication was attempted and failed. If that's the case then I can return that they're not authorised to access the resource.

If there's no Authorisation header then the user did not try to authenticate (the API that I'm using only supports Bearer Authentication - nothing else), and so I am safe to treat the user as anonymous.

From my tests, this approach seems to behave how I would like, although it does feel like something of a hack. Is there a reason why I shouldn't do it this way that I can't see?

Thanks,

Richard.

Comment: Is this the same end point or different end points in your API?

Comment: It's the same endpoint - basically what I have now can return different content depending on whether the user is logged in or not, but when the token is incorrect I need the endpoint to return a 401 response. By the way, I must thank you - it was your tutorial on oAuth that allowed me to get this far!

Comment: You are welcome, happy that my posts were useful, will reply to your question in the answers section now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this in single endpoint which accepts anonymous and authenticated users in the same time, my recommendation is to create 2 end points and pull your business logic to a private method, something like the below should work for you

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("ActionForAnon")]
public IHttpActionResult ActionForAnon()
{
    return DoYourLogic();
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("ActionForAuth")]
public IHttpActionResult ActionForAuth()
{

    return DoYourLogic();

}

private IHttpActionResult DoYourLogic()
{
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //Your response for authenticated user
    }
    else {
        //Your response for anonymous user
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I can certainly do that, but I would rather not have different endpoints that clients have to call. I've updated the question to include the proposed solution, so the question now becomes is there any reason that I shouldn't do it like this (I would say that it feels like a hack to me, I'm sure there's a better way to do it but I'm not sure exactly where in the chain it should really be done)

Comment: Well, if you do not want to expose 2 endpoints then you can use your way, but I believe it might not work because once you override the IzAuthorized attribute the attribute [AllowAnonymous] will not work any more.

Comment: Thanks for the warning - I'm not sure why it might not work, but I would freely admit that I probably don't yet understand how these two attributes are related. In my case though, everything seems to be working as desired - endpoints that require authorisation work, endpoints that don't care about authorisation work, and endpoints that handle both authenticated and unauthenticated requests differently also work, so everything looks to be in order.